# Is this an example of efficiency versus maintainability and readability? List Comprehension Python

Tags: performance, python-3.x, logic, list-comprehension

I was doing a leet code problem called two sum, which is below:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
>
> Example:
>
> > Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
> >
> > Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
> >     return [0, 1].

The code I wrote is:

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    return [num for num in nums if (target-num) in nums and (target-num) != num]
```

Is this considered too abstruse? Are there faster ways to accomplish this task without losing out on readability? To me this seems legible and easy to understand but I would like a someone else to check.

I understand the caveats of the argument of efficiency vs. readability: and I am not trying to make a program more efficient. This is purely an educational question for my own benefit (and ego I suppose); I just want to know if this is the preferred method of attack.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems according to the assumption, you only need to do "return [num for num in nums if (target-num) in nums]" if same number used twice is considered as a duplicate result.

Comment: also seems the requirement is to get the indexes of the two numbers, but twoSum returns the actual numbers.

Comment: i think your approach is a good one. but there may be an advantage to use a conventional loop because you can return as soon as you find the solution. if the average size of the list is big, the gain may be significant.

Comment: also any references to coding problem websites (better than leetcode their online IDE for submitting problems is abhorrent) or pythonic preferred methods and algorithms would be greatly greatly appreciated

Comment: Awesome thanks @Shiping, didn't take into account the size of the list increasing.

Comment: When I did 'return [num for num in nums if (target-num) in nums]' it fails since with input: nums=[3,2,4] and target = 6, [3,2,4] is returned. With my solution you get [2,4].... (check use cases, each element only used once which deals with your dupe results).